# rails order by association through another association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

As a simple example, let's say a bookstore has books which have one author. The books has many sales through orders. Authors can have many books.

I am looking for a way to list the authors ordered by sales. Since the sales are associated with books, not authors, how can I accomplish this?

I would guess something like:
`Author.order("sales.count").joins(:orders => :sales)`

but that returns a column can't be found error.

I have been able to connect them by defining it in the Author model. The following displays the correct count for sales, but it does ping the database for each and every author... bad. I'd much rather eager load them, but I can't seem to get it to work properly since it will not list any authors who happen to have 0 sales if I remove the self.id and assign the join to @authors.

```
    class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

      def sales_count
        Author.where(id: self.id).joins(:orders => :sales).count
      end
    end
```

And more specifically, how can I order them by the count result so I can list the most popular authors first?

Comment: Maybe `Author.joins(:orders => :sales).order("COUNT(sales.*) DESC")` ?

Comment: That snippet will generate invalid SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let's have all associations available on the Author class itself to keep the query code simple.

```
class Author < AR::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :orders, :through => :books
  has_many :sales, :through => :orders
end
```

The simplest approach would be for you to use `group` with `count`, which gets you a hash in the form `{author-id: count}`:

```
author_counts = Author.joins(:sales).group("authors.id").count
=> {1 => 3, 2 => 5, ... }
```

You can now sort your authors and lookup the count using the `author_counts` hash (authors with no sales will return `nil`):

```
<% Author.all.sort_by{|a| author_counts[a.id] || 0}.reverse.each do |author| %>
  <%= author.name %>: <%= author_counts[author.id] || 0 %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

An alternative approach would be to use the [ar_outer_joins](https://github.com/elabs/ar_outer_joins) gem that allows you get around the limitations of using `includes` to generate a LEFT JOIN:

```
authors = Author.outer_joins(:sales).
                 group(Author.column_names.map{|c| "authors.#{c}").
                 select("authors.*, COUNT(sales.id) as sales_count").
                 order("COUNT(sales.id) DESC")
```

Now your view can just look like this:

```
<% authors.each do |author| %>
  <%= author.name %>: <%= author.sales_count %>
<% end %>
```

This example demonstrates how useful a LEFT JOIN can be where you can't (or specifically don't want to) eager load the other associations. I have no idea why `outer_joins` isn't included in ActiveRecord by default.

Comment: Would this work for making a book product filter system where there each filter group is sorted by popularity? Books would then have a very large number of `has_many`, is that good practice for long term?

 I have a lot of other info I'd like to sort through, most popular genre of books, most popular book publisher, most popular illustrator, etc.

Comment: Put the `author_counts` definition into the author model, and used `@authors = Author.all` in the controller, and the view `@authors.sort_by` snippet. It works great, though the development log shows a long multi-join query for each author. If I have 100 authors, and want to also include other filters like publisher, illustrator, etc wont this get out of hand?

Comment: I moved all the code into the view the way you laid it out and sure enough, only it only performs 1 query now. Which best practice do I choose to follow? Simplify views or reducing queries?

Comment: Likely an N+1 issue that can benefit from eager loading.  Are you using any attributes in your view from associated models that aren't contained in the Author model itself?

Comment: That's the problem, many.
It's a product filter so it needs a lot of information from the products that aren't typically related to each other. List authors by sales, list genres by downloads, etc.

Comment: Can you post your model and desired view code to give an idea of the associations involved?

Comment: Aw man, I just figured out how to properly use the outer_joins gem.... Got it! Awesome.